# GitHub pages: 404 on / but /index.html works fine

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

my situation is the following:

- I have deployed a jekyll site to github using the [`docs` folder on the `master` branch](https://github.com/n6g7/redux-saga-firebase/tree/master/docs)
- It has a [markdown index file](https://github.com/n6g7/redux-saga-firebase/blob/master/docs/index.md)
- [*username*.github.io/*repo*/index.html](https://n6g7.github.io/redux-saga-firebase/index.html) works
- [*username*.github.io/*repo*/](https://n6g7.github.io/redux-saga-firebase/) returns a 404

The site works well locally using `jekyll serve` (no 404).

I'd expect GitHub to return the content of index.html when receiving a request for a directory.

Could it be a problem with markdown?

Comment: both return the same page for me, no 404s

Comment: @StephenG interesting, it may be Fastly's cached page that I see then. I'll try again in a few hours. Thanks!